# rsyslog: peer name not authorized - not permitted to talk to it

Tags: ssl, rsyslog

Trying to configure an rsyslog central server with TLS turned on. It's been a struggle so far, but I'm almost there. Currently getting this error:

```
rsyslogd: error: peer name not authorized -  not permitted to talk to
it. Names:  [v8.27.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2088 ]  
rsyslogd: netstream session 0x7fda34010110 from 10.0.4.91 will be closed due to
error  [v8.27.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2089 ]
```

But I specifically put that IP into `InputTCPServerStreamDriverPermittedPeer`. What could be wrong? I can't get past this error. Validated my configuration is OK with

```
# rsyslogd -N1
rsyslogd: version 8.27.0, config validation run (level 1), master config /etc/rsyslog.conf
rsyslogd: End of config validation run. Bye.
```

My Config with a few things stripped:

```
$ModLoad imuxsock # local messages

$ModLoad imtcp # TCP listener  

$ModLoad imjournal # provides access to the systemd journal

$DefaultNetstreamDriver gtls

$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /etc/rsyslog.d/ca.pem 

$DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile /etc/rsyslog.d/machine-cert.pem 

$DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile /etc/rsyslog.d/machine-key.pem 

$InputTCPServerStreamDriverAuthMode x509/name

$InputTCPServerStreamDriverPermittedPeer 10.0.4.91

$InputTCPServerStreamDriverMode 1 #run driver in TLS-only mode

$InputTCPServerRun 10514 #start up listener at port 10514

# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/

$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf

*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that the client was supplying an untrusted certificate.

Steps to figure this out:

1. On client, run:
   openssl s_client -connect :10514
   and remediate any errors
2. on server, run:
   openssl s_client -connect :10514
3. in rsyslogd.conf, switch:
   $InputTCPServerStreamDriverAuthMode x509/name
   to
   $InputTCPServerStreamDriverAuthMode anon
   that allows any client to connect without authorizing the client. This ought to allow events to be submitted.

This narrowed it down to a client cert issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your rsyslog has allowed TLS client talk to peer 10.0.4.91

```
$InputTCPServerStreamDriverPermittedPeer 10.0.4.91
```

You have to make sure the server certificate has `CN=10.0.4.91`

Setting `$InputTCPServerStreamDriverAuthMode` to `anon` is not recommended as insecure.

You can find more details at https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/tutorials/tls_cert_errmsgs.html